Task index out of bounds in Python 1 Script
My problem is very similar to a previous issue posted in here :
IndexError: index out of bounds
I am adapting the code developed for an XL-Release Community plugin. This original comunity "plugin", is nothing more but a Task that iterates over lists and creates as many tasks as the items of a list. We did some small changes to this original code in order to iterate lists of a python dictionary, and I am getting an error on this method :
def addTaskToChangeVariable(value):
    scriptTask = taskApi.newTask("xlrelease.ScriptTask")
    print("The task is {} ".format(scriptTask))
    scriptTask.script = "releaseVariables.update({})".format(value)
    scriptTask.title = "{} ".format(value)
    scriptTask = phaseApi.addTask(task.container.id, scriptTask, position)
    # taskApi.lockTask(scriptTask.id)

The error is :
javax.script.ScriptException: com.xebialabs.deployit.checks.Checks$IncorrectArgumentException: com.xebialabs.deployit.checks.Checks$IncorrectArgumentException: Task index out of bounds in  at line number 103
I am still troubleshooting this error on XL-Release

I believe your out-of-bounds error occurs because the position is beyond the index of tasks within your phase.  This script works to assign value "bar" to text variable "foo" if your custom task is at the top of the phase, with index = 0.  You just need to know or compute a valid position.
def addTaskToChangeVariable(varname, value):
    scriptTask = taskApi.newTask("xlrelease.ScriptTask")
    print("The task is {} ".format(scriptTask))
    scriptTask.script = "releaseVariables['{}'] = '{}'".format(varname, value)
    scriptTask.title = "{} ".format(varname)
    scriptTask = phaseApi.addTask(task.container.id, scriptTask, position)
    # taskApi.lockTask(scriptTask.id)

position = 1
addTaskToChangeVariable("foo", "bar")

